# How do I use OAuth's user model as foreing key in my models?

Tags: python, django

I am using `social-auth-app-django==2.1.0` and I am trying to create a model in my models.py which uses the user as a foreing key.I've looked through the documentation but couldn't find anything related to that matter. So right now my models.py looks like this:

```
class Deck(models):
    deck_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(USER_MODEL ) #what do I type here?

class Card(models):
    card_back = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    card_front = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    card_strength = models.IntegerField()
    card_last_trained = models.DateTimeField()
    deck = models.ForeignKey(Deck, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it. I imported `from social_django import models as oauth_models`
then I used it as a foreing key like that: `user_id = models.ForeignKey(oauth_models.USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`